# Auto resize height of textarea function not selected dynamic added elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, textarea, autosize

I'm planing do auto resizing textarea like facebook and I found this plugin([Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)). It works great on me. But when I add new textarea this plugin not selected this. I know i must change selector into plugin. But no result. How can I solve this problem? Thank You!

I'm calling this plugin like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').autosize();   
});
```

I think I must change on line 56: `return this.each(...)` to `return $('textarea').each(...)` but not working. Where is my error?

Comment: Please insert the relevant code and HTML into a JSFiddle if you can. Out of context this is bit of a fishing expedition :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. Where selected elements I change to `$(body).on('input scroll keyup')...` And it works. Thank you for explains.